# Attention mechanism with different hidden states length?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, attention

i have two layer with different layer sizes (hidden states) how can i perform encoder decoder type of attention on these layers if the layer sizes are different? because i will do dot product, how?

Consider I have two layers:

lstm1 = LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, name='lstm')

lstm2 = LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, name='lstm')

How is possible to apply attention here since dot product would be not possible?

Thanks

Comment: And these `lstm1` and `lstm2` these are two independent encoders and you want to use one decoder attending to both of them?

Comment: how can you calculate similarity in 2 different vector spaces? how similar is a centimeter to a square meter?